# GPIO - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: device_reference

Tags: java, embedded, gpio

I've inherited a project which involves a java program setting GPIO pins on a bespoke board.

- Linux: Built with yocto, version 4.9.59
- Java: zulu embedded, openjdk version "1.8.0_131".
- The libdio.so is part of KURA_3.1.0.

Calling...

```
    GPIOPinConfig config = new GPIOPinConfig(DeviceConfig.DEFAULT,
            pinNumber, 0, 1, 3, false);
    GPIOPin pin = getPin(config);
```

I get...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: device_reference
    at com.oracle.dio.gpio.impl.GPIOPinImpl.openPinByConfig0(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.dio.gpio.impl.GPIOPinImpl.<init>(GPIOPinImpl.java:63)
    at com.oracle.dio.gpio.impl.GPIOPinFactory.create(GPIOPinFactory.java:47)
    at com.oracle.dio.gpio.impl.GPIOPinFactory.create(GPIOPinFactory.java:38)
    at jdk.dio.DeviceManager.openWithConfig(DeviceManager.java:290)
    at jdk.dio.DeviceManager.open(DeviceManager.java:273)
    at jdk.dio.DeviceManager.open(DeviceManager.java:209)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had `jdk.dio-1.0.300.jar` on my classpath.

When I changed this to `jdk.dio-1.0.100.jar` the error went away.